# for my code iam not getting pagenation and searchbar in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

//here is my code//

```
class TableList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //var totalPages = 100 / 10; // 10 page numbers

    this.state = {
      query: "",
      countries: [],
      searchString:[],

      currentPageNumber: 1,
      pageOfItems: [],
      totalItems: 4,
      itemsPerPage: 10

    }



 this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
  }
  onChangePage(pageOfItems) {

    this.setState({ pageOfItems: pageOfItems });
}

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        query: event.target.value
    },()=>{
  this.filterArray();
})

}
handleSelect(number) {
  console.log('handle select', number);
  this.setState({currentPageNumber: number});
}
  componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = 'https://indian-cities-api-nocbegfhqg.now.sh/cities';
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {

          this.setState({
            countries: result,
            searchString:result,
            currentPageNumber:result.currentPageNumber,
            totalItems: result.totalItems,
            itemsPerPage: result.itemsPerPage
          });

        },

      )
  }
  filterArray = () => {
    let searchString = this.state.query;
    let result = this.state.countries;


    if(searchString.length > 0){

      result = result.filter(searchString);
this.setState({
  result
})
  }

}

  render() {
    const { countries} = this.state;
    let totalPages = Math.ceil(this.state.totalItems / this.state.numItemsPerPage);


      return(

        <div>
          <div className="container">

          </div>
          <h2>countrie List</h2>
          <form>
                <input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Search for..."  onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
            </form>
          <Table>
          <Pagination
                    bsSize="medium"
                    items={totalPages}
                    activePage={this.state.currentPageNumber} onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}/>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#ID</th>
                <th>countrie Name</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>States</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {countries.map(countrie => (
                <tr key={countrie.City}>
                  <td>{countrie.sno}</td>
                  <td>{countrie.City}</td>
                  <td>{countrie.State}</td>
                  <td>{countrie.District}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}

            </tbody>

          </Table>
        </div>
      )
              }

            }           
      export default TableList;
```

```
//the error coming is

Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `Wadi`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version
```

Comment: duplicated city (used for key) in api provided data

Answer (score 0):

IN SHORT:

- Search - filtered data stored in `this.state.result` - not used in render

  `this.setState({
    result
  })`

  as `{ result }` is a short of `{ result: result }` and **this is good** ... overwriting `this.state.countries` would result in source data loss (needs refetching)

  `render` gets/make use of `this.state.countries` - always full dataset, not filtered by search, not divided by page ranges

  You need to copy some data into `this.state.result` after fetching (not copy a `countries` reference)
- Pagination - 'results' (not proper as above) records not subselected by range based on `currentPage`

Inspect state changes (check if properly working) in browser using react dev tools.

Comment: could u please explain breifly i didnit get please help me

Comment: could u please modify i didni't get

Comment: explore some "making todo in react" tutorial then back to this